# MongoDB - How to check if two field has same value if one of the field is in object of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  "name": "John",
  "originalName": {
    "students": [
    {
    "orgName": "John"
    },
    {
    "orgName": "Stuart"
    }
  ]
  }
}
```

I need to check if `name` and `orignalName.students.orgName` are same. In the above code `John` is similar. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Your coding attempt please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query 1:** This below query will get you all docs, Where if any of the `orgName` in students array match with `name` field's value.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $in: [
      "$name",
      "$originalName.students.orgName"
    ]
  }
})
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sJazL8I3edd)

**Query 2:** This below aggregation query will add a new field as `true/false` to all docs, based on if any of the `orgName` in students array match with `name` field's value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchingValueExists: {
        $in: [
          "$name",
          "$originalName.students.orgName"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2T17YH6EMEk)